# File.ReadLines "Can't Read From Closed TextReader"

Tags: c#, file, readline

I have been getting a wierd excepction that i am not sure what is causing it. In my local machine when i use:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("filePath");
foreach(string line in lines)...
```

This works perfectly without any problems. The code is inside a project built on .NetFramework 4.5. The dll is referenced from a website that is hosted on a .NetFramework 4.0 pool.

Once i upload my work to the host and start using it, all instances in the code that uses the `File.ReadLines` throws an exception. I replaced the code with `File.ReadAllLines` and it worked.

I have read many questions about this, but i don't think any of them answers why this happens. Could it be the .NetFramework version or is it something else ?

Comment: Hi ykh, how did you solve it ? I am facing same issue. ReadAllLines is not good when we are reading huge files since it tries to load the whole file in the memory. So i also have to use ReadLine too. But hitting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadLine` method was introduced with .NET Framework 4.0, while `ReadAllLines` was introduces with .NET Framework 2.0. So, probably the problem is the .NET version.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that ReadLines only lets you iterate through the lines once, under the hood that method does something similar to this:

```
private IENumerable<string> ReadLine(string path)
{
    var file = OpenFile(path);
    while (file.Read())
    {
        yield return file.GetLine();
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

This means that the file is open until you finish interating through the IEnumerable and is closed as soon as you reach the end of it. Maybe it would be simpler for you to call ReadAllLines, which returns a good old string[] that let's you iterate through it at will.

Comment: I am familiar with how ReadLines works and its actually working fine on my local machine and i never had any problems with it. Temporally i have replaced with with ReadAllLines which is fine, but when i hosted the code, it started behaving strange.

Comment: Well, I cannot think of other cause for this error than the enumerator closing the file. Without further context is hard to think of another possibility, is this crashing all the time on your server machine or is it something that sometimes happens? if the latter is 'lines' an instance field or is it inside of a method?

Comment: Yes, its always happening on my server machine, and the "lines" is inside a method.